# switch between views without losing their data | wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am new to WPF , c# and want to build an application which will has more than one view but when switching the views i lose the cache

i have buttons with command to switch between views

the MultipleView class :

```
    class MultipleView : ObservableObject
{

    public RelayCmmand HOMEVIEWCOMMAND { get; set; }
    public RelayCmmand SECANDVIEWCOMMAND { get; set; }
    public RelayCmmand SEARCHVIEWCOMMAND { get; set; }

    public ViewModel HomeVm { get; set; }
    public Pdfview PDFVm { get; set; }
    public SearchViewModel SearchVm { get; set; }

private Object _currentView;

    public Object CurrentView
    {
        get { return _currentView; }
        set
        {
            _currentView = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public MultipleView()
    {
        HomeVm = new ViewModel();
        PDFVm = new Pdfview();
        SearchVm = new SearchViewModel();
        CurrentView = HomeVm;

        HOMEVIEWCOMMAND = new RelayCmmand(o =>
        {
            CurrentView = HomeVm;

        });
        SECANDVIEWCOMMAND = new RelayCmmand(o =>
        {
            CurrentView = PDFVm;

        });
        SEARCHVIEWCOMMAND = new RelayCmmand(o =>
        {
            CurrentView = SearchVm;

        });
    }
}
```

the DataTemplate in app.xaml :

```
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodel:ViewModel}">
            <view:ViewList/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodel:Pdfview}">
            <view:Sacand/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodel:SearchViewModel}">
            <view:SearchView/>
        </DataTemplate>
```

my questions is :
how i can switch without losing data ?

Comment: What happened to your command propertties, have you poured beer over your keyboard and your Shift key got stuck? Make sure you don't create and assign the DataContext in your UserControls.

Comment: What data are you losing? Is whatever you're talking about definitely successfully transferring from view to viewmodel?